# POST http://localhost/myapp/index.php/myCon/verification 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Here am checking if the user entered code is same as the code which is in the database for which I have raised AJAX request in the view. In another function I used the same code, over there the request is sent and I have received the response but here am getting error 'POST http://localhost/myapp/index.php/myCon/verification 500 (Internal Server Error)'. I'm unable to find what causing that error.

Base URL:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myapp/';
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function newPass(){
    var temp = jQuery("#code").val();
    console.log('code:'+temp);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>index.php/myCon/verification", //**getting error here**
        data: {"temp":temp},
        success:function(response){
            console.log("response"+response);
            var msg = response.message;
            var stat = response.status;
            if(stat == 'success'){
                //some statements
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Incorrect code';
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            console.log("Status: " + textStatus); console.log("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  
    /**
    * 
    */
    class MyCon extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        //there is another function in which am calling AJAX request too it is working but am getting error while calling this verification.
        public function verification(){
            if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
                $this->load->model('CustomerModel');
                $res = $this->CustomerModel->checkCode();
                echo "count:".$res->num_rows(); // this caused the problem
                if(!empty($res)) {
                    $data['status'] = 'success';
                    $data['message'] = 'code found';
                } else {
                    $data['status'] = 'error';
                    $data['message'] = 'Data not found';
                }
                echo json_encode($data);
                exit;
            }
            else{
                redirect('index.php/myCon/fp_confirm');   
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Model:

```
<?php
    class CustomerModel extends CI_Model{
        function __construct()
        {
            parent:: __construct();
        }
        function checkCode(){
            $code = $this->input->post('temp');
            $result = $this->db->get_where('privilege_customer', array('code_password' => $code));
            return $result->result();
        }
   }
?>
```

Comment: You should enable error display and / or check the server's error log to see what the error is exactly.

Comment: where is `myCon` controller in this code?

Comment: @PankajMakwana hahah fogot to change it. Now go through the code I have edited it.

Comment: try with base_url instead of site_url...

Comment: @Mahesh no change still getting the same error.

Comment: url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/myCon/verification'); ?>",         or if you're using htaccess                                                                                          url: "<?php echo base_url('/myCon/verification'); ?>",

Comment: did you use `.htaccess` file for rewritting?

Comment: no I didn't use .htaccess @PankajMakwana

Comment: @Mahesh no I didn't create any .htaccess file

Comment: did you try to print errors by enabling the error_reporting? 500 internal error will be shown on production environment. Try to change the env in config file.

Comment: @AkHilRegonda may i know you controller file name?

Comment: Actually I have used another AJAX request in another view with another function, It's working fine but am getting here while accessing this function.

Comment: check your console,whether you're getting any jquery errors...

Comment: thanks guys!! I have changed the log_threshold value and enabled error_reporting found I was calling num_rows() that was the error. I removed it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

> echo "count:".$res->num_rows(); // this caused the problem

I have called num_rows() function in the controller. Got the following error in log file: 'Severity: Error --> Call to a member function num_rows() on array __'

I have removed the echo statement and it worked.